# Javascript - select only the first 5 non-empty lines from textarea

Tags: javascript, html

In a simple HTML script, I have two elements: textarea and a non-working Javascript script (below). My goal is to only select UP TO first 5 non-empty lines from the textarea (each line is split by \n). This code:

var textarea = document.getElementbyId('data').value;

selects all (10) rows from the textarea, but I only want to select up to 5 rows and ignore the rest. I put my unworking attempt here - http://jsfiddle.net/1xst7e22/

---

**TEXTAREA**

```
<textarea id="data" style="width:100%;height:300px">
January
February

March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
</textarea>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** (it's my miserable attempt, not working..): assuming x = 5:

```
function getLines (x)
{
var textarea = document.getElementbyId('data');
var firstX = (textarea.value ? textarea.value + "\n" : "");

      if (firstX.length > x) firstX = firstX.slice(x);

      textarea.value = firstX.join("\n");
}
```

--

So when the script is working, the textarea = document.getElementbyId('data').value; should hold only these lines:

```
January
February
March
April
May
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = document.getElementById('data');
var dataArray = data.value.split("\n");
dataArray = dataArray.slice(0,5);
data.value = dataArray.join("\n");
```

```html
<textarea id="data" style="width:100%;height:300px">
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
</textarea>
```

Comment: Ok, but what about removing empty lines, could you show me how too? Thanks.

Comment: @Tom I believe adding this as the third line of JavaScript "dataArray = dataArray.filter(Boolean);" is an efficient way to filter out all of the false/empty elements in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
   function getLines(x) { 
        var textarea = document.getElementById('data'); 
        var firstX = textarea.innerHTML.split("\n").slice(0,x).join("\n")
        textarea.value = firstX;
    }
```